# return will not function with array

Tags: arrays, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

From solidity:

> TypeError: Return argument type address payable[] storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) address.
> --> contract.sol:32:16:
> |
> 32 |         return players;
> |                ^^^^^^^

```
function getPlayers() public view returns (address) {
        return players;
    }
```

I am trying to return the number of players in the array. any help? solidity 8.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the entire array. Since you want the length of the array, the return value length of the array is uint type. change the `returns` type to `uint`

```
function getPlayers() public view returns (uint) {
        return players.length;
    }
```

If you want to return the array itself

```
// error states this: type address payable[]
function getPlayers() public view returns (address payable[] memory ) {
        return players;
    }
```